# Javascript: variable in outer function not changed by inner function

Tags: javascript, closures

I am having a small issue with what I believe is probably my misunderstanding of Javascript closures.

I have this piece of code --

```
getStdOpts: function(tbl, filt) {
    var vals = new Array();

    this.srvs.getStdOptions(
        { tbl: tbl },
        {
            'ok': function(rsp) {
                for (var i in rsp) {
                    vals.push({ value: rsp[i].id, text: rsp[i].descr });
                }
            }
        }
    );
    return vals;
}
```

In essence, although the inner function inside the getStdOptions call ('ok': function...) pushes new values into the vals array, when accessed from outside the call, the vals array is empty.  When accessed from within the inner function, vals contains all the elements as expected.

Would really appreciate any help I can get on this matter.

Comment: `getStdOptions` might be performing some asynchronous operation, otherwise there would not really be a reason to pass a callback. I.e. `vals` is returned before the `ok` function is run. To help you better, we'd know what `this.srvs.getStdOptions` is doing.

Comment: Hi Felix, the `getStdOptions` function calls a back-end data service to retrieve a list of options from a given table `tbl`, and part of the response from that service would be a status _ok_, and a list of options.  You might be right, I did not think about the fact that the service retrieval operation might be asynchronous.  I will play around with the code again and let you know if I've gotten it working.  Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is a closure/scope issue.  If `this.srvs.getStdOptions` is an asynchronous operation, your `getStdOpts` is always going to return an empty array.  This array would be filled once the operation completes, which, as written, would be after you would need it.  You're going to have to handle things a bit differently.  Either you need to directly pass into `getStdOpts` a callback which would take `vals` as a parameter and execute that callback within your anonymous one for `this.srvs.getStdOptions`, or you need to return some sort of *promise* object to which you can add callbacks (which would essentially take the same `vals` as a parameter) as needed-- you'd have to resolve in your anonymous callback your promise to have `vals` as its "promised" results.